# How to centerlast a caption in a beamer

Tags: beamer, captions

There is a problem when I want to `centering` the caption in the `beamer`. And I find that the `caption` package is useless in the `beamer`

And this my **MWE**:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[font=scriptsize,justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{My caption here but I can't center the last line of caption}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{My other caption here}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and this is my outcome:

[image]

So,how can I fix the problem?

Comment: I cannot confirm your result, i.e. if I'm compiling your AWE I get a different result. It seems that you are not using the latest caption package, which is adapted to the recent version of beamer. So updating your caption package (or your whole TeX system) should help.

Comment: @Haomiao.Zhang: You need to update your distribution. See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: As has been mentioned, updating your distribution solves the problem; if, for some reason, this is not an option, remove the `caption` package and add to the preamble `\defbeamertemplate*{caption}{centered}
{%
  \centering\footnotesize
  {%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{caption name}%
    \usebeamerfont*{caption name}%
    \insertcaptionname
    \usebeamertemplate{caption label separator}%
  }%
  \insertcaption\par
}`

Comment: However, it's not clear to me why you mention centerlast but use `\centering`; those are different things. Do you want to center the whole caption or just the last line?

Answer (score 5):

Add the `caption` package option `justification=centering`.
`\usepackage[font=scriptsize,justification=centering]{caption}`

That should center all lines.

Answer (score 0):

To simultaneously remove "Figure" before caption and justify it:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}    
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\centering\insertcaption\par}
```